# How to perform a flip when a button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick

What I have till now is a list which shows up when I swipe with my finger from the left-side of the screen. I also have a button but I don't know how to make that button make the same action as the finger does.

I have a main class, `MainActivity` which `extends Action` and 2 other classes which `extends Fragment`. The button is called `menuButton`.

This is my code, in `menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` is where I tried to make that happen.

```
public class ActivityTypes extends Fragment implements BluetoothListener {
    private ActivityEntity currentActivityEntity;
    private ArrayList<ActivityDetalis> activityDetailsList = new ArrayList<ActivityDetalis>();
    private String startDateTime = "", endDateTime = "";
    private static int idLastActivity;

    int activityType = 1;
    private Button menuButton;

    private BluetoothMeterService bluetoothMeterService;
    private static final String TAG = "DeviceListActivity";

    public static final String START_FROM_PAUSED_ACTIVITY_FLAG = "START_FROM_PAUSED_ACTIVITY_FLAG";

    private String deviceAdress;
    private View rootView;
    public static boolean noMessages;
    public ImageView heart;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_screen, container, false);
        initialization();

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());



        SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(ConnectionScreen.PREFS_NAME,0);
        boolean autoConnect = settings.getBoolean("autoConnect",false);
        deviceAdress = settings.getString("deviceAdress","");
        if (autoConnect == true) {
            bluetoothMeterService = new BluetoothMeterService(new Handler());
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BluetoothMeterService.class);
            intent.putExtra("deviceAdress", deviceAdress);

            BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAdress);
            bluetoothMeterService.connect(device);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Already connected to " + device.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("test", "AlreadyConnected");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("test","Disconnected");
        }
        //TODO updateDetails();

    }
    private void initialization(){
        final Spinner spinnerOfActivities = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_activities);

        menuButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_menu);
        spinnerOfActivities.setAdapter(new ActivitySpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_spinner,
                activities,total_images));
        spinnerOfActivities.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String selectedActivity = (String) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                activityType = 1;
                for (EnumActivities.ActivitiesModeEnum act : EnumActivities.ActivitiesModeEnum.values()) {
                    if (act.getActivityName().equals(selectedActivity.toUpperCase())) {
                        activityType = act.getActivityNumber();
                        break;
                    }
                };

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        spinnerOfActivities.setPopupBackgroundResource(R.color.Blue);

        menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        });


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(ActivityDetalis activityDetalis) {
        Log.e("OBSERVER ACTIVITY", activityDetalis.toString());

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                heart.setColorFilter(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue));
            }
        });
        // TODO - UI
        if(start == true && pause == false)
            updateUI(activityDetalis);
        // TODO - ADD TO LIST
        ActivityEntity activity = new ActivityEntity(activityType,startDateTime,endDateTime);
        activityDetailsList.add(activityDetalis);
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly. I suggest you to use Android Drawer Layout .Please check this link.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

go through '**Open and Close with the App Icon**' topic

Comment: I don't know which part of the code is responsible with the sliding action. I run it but this is what I get in my console: `08-08 13:09:42.125    3161-3161/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
08-08 13:09:42.125    3161-3161/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
08-08 13:09:42.155    3161-3161/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
`